# Angular PWA no lee Manifest

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, pwa, manifest

Estoy instalando una aplicación angular pwa en iis en windows server, estoy instalando la web app como una sub aplicacion de un sitio web. Al generar la app uso el código `ng build --prod --base-href "/test-pwa/"`y todo funciona bien el problema es que no me lee el manifest, aparece el típico problema "Error línea 1...." que básicamente no encuentra el archivo pero esta la etiqueta link en el html.

Como información adicional, service worker se registra y hasta puedo hacer push notifications, pero para la instalación me falla el manifest.

En archivo angular.json esta como corresponde:

```
projects: {
   ...
   architect: {
      ...
      build: {
         options: {
            ... 
            assets: [
               "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
         }
      ...
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: La etiqueta `link` se generó con la subruta base? Es decir `/test-pwa/manifest.json`? Sino quizás sea un bug de Angular pwa o una configuración adicional

Comment: la etiqueta link no, voy a probar eso y te comento

Comment: @Vlady nope, sin suerte, probé "/test-pwa/manifest.webmanifest" y "./manifest.webmanifest"

Comment: El manifest generado tiene que ser un json `manifest.json`, en tu index.html la ruta del manifest tiene la subruta? o qué ruta generó, por ejemplo en un proyecto vue con iis tengo `/contratos/_nuxt/manifest.0e91527f.json`, supongo que en Angular tiene que ser igual o parecido

Comment: @Vlady en angular te lo genera en la ruta raíz y le dices que es parte del proyecto en el archivo angular.json (en el extracto de json que agregué). Angular me genera el manifest con esa extensión (webmanifest), voy a probar si al cambiarle la extensión a json hace alguna diferencia

Comment: @Vlady no alcancé a probar si era eso pero es bastante probable ya que tuve que agregar el MIME Type webmanifest para que iis me lo permitiese descargar

Answer (score 1):

Solución encontrada, IIS no me deja descargar archivos webmanifest, creo que me hubiese ahorrado problemas si usaba manifest.json, dejo un link a la solución

[Add MIME Type webmanifest to IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566446/how-can-i-have-iis-properly-serve-webmanifest-files-on-my-web-site)

Comment: Buenísimo, no conocía esa opción (limitación) del IIS, sería bueno que pongas la solución acá manteniendo el link de la fuente.